# cannot add file to stage with git with `git add .`: zsh enters a text editor mode

Tags: git, terminal, zsh, git-stage

In my home directory I'm trying to move files not staged to commit to staged as well as track new file. When entering `git add .`, instead of staging the file, the cursor goes down one line but no command is executed. (as show below where `|` is the position of the cursor

```
$mac@home$
|
```

I tried that same command in other repository and works properly there.

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: try `git add . --force`. Have you make any changes in `.gitignore`?

Comment: Many thanks for your comment @SwissCodeMen. I had indeed added folder to gitignore. I removed them (as well as another one which was already linked to a git repo) and it solved the problem! many thanks again